What are good configs for running UNet3DConditionModel on 8 GB VRAM? (64x64x64 inputs)
What are good configs for running UNet3DConditionModel on 8 GB VRAM? (64x64x64 inputs)
More specifically for this project I'm looking to use HuggingFace's UNet3DConditionModel on my home PC on a RTX 3060 Ti for voxel generation of small (64x64x64) models, but I'm struggling to find a good setup that would fit within the VRAM of my GPU. I doubt the model will be very effective with the space limitations I have so I'll probably swap to another model later, but I'd like to try out a setup with the UNet3DConditionModel first so any recommendations that don't require a more powerful computer?
